# Android intent-filter for multiple NFC types

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, ndef

Would someone be able to explain the syntax for setting up an intent-filter for multiple types of NDEF records?  I have an Android app that is writing binary data to the NFC tag using an 'external' type record, but then the tag is connected to a host which responds with a mimeType of 'text/plain'.

I would like to be able to read and write both types from the Android phone.

I can read one or the other (text/plain or ext) if I have the intent filter set up just for that one type and the tag data corresponds, but I do not know how to modify the manifest such that the app will be opened for either one of those types.

Thank you.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.mYapp.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <!-- <data android:mimeType="text/plain" /> -->
        <data android:pathPrefix="/prefix:r" android:host="ext" android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to match *either* a URI (that's how the external type name is passed in the intent) *or* a MIME type (text/plain), you need to declare two separate intent filters for them. Otherwise Android's intent filter matching logic will only try to match intents that contain both, the URI and the MIME type.

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="/prefix:r" android:host="ext" android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```